# Ordering by a column that doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was looking at an example in my database programming book (it uses MySql) of how to select a random row from a table:

```
SELECT * FROM Bugs ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

I'm confused about how you can order by a nonexistant column. Is that the equivalent of

```
SELECT *, RAND() AS temp FROM BUGS ORDER BY temp LIMIT 1;
```

except vanquishing the the `temp` column from the results?

Answer (score 0):

It is basically the same thing.  The only difference is that the value is not in the result set.  There is another subtle difference.  The `rand()` in the `select` should be evaluated once per row in `Bugs`.  I think the `rand()` in the `order by` might be evaluated more often (this depends on the implementation).  In this case, a random order is a random order either way, so this nuance doesn't make a difference.

You should not be confused by the presence of expressions in the `order by` that are not in the `select`.  This is not particularly uncommon.